# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in windows

Tags: php

I have the following error when try to install phpmyadmin in 4.0.4 on PHP version 5.4. I am running Apache 2.2 on My Windows 7. I can run  . My php is installed in c:\php. I have add the following line in php.ini but no lucks.
    extension=php_gd2.dll
    extension=php_mbstring.dll
    extension=php_exif.dll

And also this line in php.ini

```
--enable-mbstring=all
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177

I checked the phpinfo() page  but it does not show that mbstring is enabled. But I did 
extension=php_mbstring.dll

So why the mbstring is not started? 
Thanks.

what can I do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `--enable-mbstring=all` is a command-line directive when building PHP from source; it is not a php.ini setting

Comment: Is the `php_mbstring.dll` file in your extensions directory?

Comment: You need to restart Apache after making changes to php.ini .

Comment: php_mbstring.dll is in in c:\php\ext which is my php installed folder Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in php **5.5.8** and the **php.ini** file find the part called **Windows Extensions** and be sure that the extension **php_mbstring.dll** is uncomment (remove semi-colon at first) and be sure to appropriately set the **extension_dir** directive.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your php.ini file is in the correct directory. By default the path should be C:\Windows\php.ini. You can find out what it's looking for using phpinfo().